# Flex behaves differently in chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

just a simple floating action button list.
always it work like this: [behavior in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibHvj.png), is correctly

but, when it [runs in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXh18.png), is wrong. The flex box moves to the left. and did not display the text.

my html code is:

```html
    <html class="light"><head><style>
    .light {
      --background: 255, 255, 255;
      --surface: 255, 255, 255;
      --color: 0, 0, 0;
      --shadow: 0, 0, 0, .25;
      --error-background: 211, 47, 47;
      --error-color: 0, 0, 0;
      --onBackground: 18, 18, 18;
      --onSuface: 18, 18, 18;
      --onError-background: 0, 0, 0;
      --onError-color: 255, 255, 255;
    }

    * {
      min-height: 32px;
      min-width: 32px;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: rgb(var(--background));
      font-size: calc(12px + .625vmin);
      color: rgb(var(--color));
    }
    div {
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .fabs {
      z-index: 6;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      max-height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
      align-content: baseline;
      will-change: clip-path, opacity;
      transition: clip-path .3s ease-out,opacity .3s ease;
      clip-path: inset(calc(100% - 64px - 5vmin) 0 0 calc(100% - 80px - 7.5vmin));
      overflow: hidden;
      contain: layout style;
    }

    .fabs>a {
      max-width: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
      max-height: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
      min-height: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
      border-radius: calc(24px + 1.25vmin);
      background-color: rgb(var(--surface));
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: .5px solid rgb(var(--color),.2);
      box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(var(--shadow));
      margin: calc(8px + 1.25vmin) calc(16px + 2.5vmin);
      transition: max-width .5s ease;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .fabs:hover {
      clip-path: inset(0);
    }

    .fabs>a~a:hover{
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .fabs svg {
      width: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
      stroke: rgba(var(--color), .7);
    }

    .fabs>a~a::after {
      content: attr(title);
      vertical-align: top;
      line-height: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
      margin-right: calc(24px + 1.25vmin);
      color: rgb(var(--color));
    }
      </style>

      </head><body><div class="fabs" id="fabs">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-4 -4 32 32">
            <line x1="6" y1="12" x2="18" y2="12"></line>
            <line x1="12" y1="6" x2="12" y2="18"></line>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:home()" title="Home">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-4 -4 32 32">
            <polyline points="7 10.2,7 17,10.5 17,10.5 12,13.5 12,13.5 17,17 17,17 10.2" fill="#fff0"></polyline>
            <polyline points="5 11,12 5,19 11" fill="#fff0"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'})" title="Top">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-4 -4 32 32">
            <line x1="8" y1="7" x2="16" y2="7"></line>
            <polyline points="8 13,12 9,16 13" fill="#fff0"></polyline>
            <line x1="12" y1="10" x2="12" y2="18"></line>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:theme(+1)" title="Turn Theme">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-8 -8 40 40">
            <path fill="#fff0" d="M22.6 11.29L20 8.69V5c0-.55-.45-1-1-1h-3.69l-2.6-2.6c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0L8.69 4H5c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v3.69l-2.6 2.6c-.39.39-.39 1.02 0 1.41L4 15.3V19c0 .55.45 1 1 1h3.69l2.6 2.6c.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0l2.6-2.6H19c.55 0 1-.45 1-1v-3.69l2.6-2.6c.39-.39.39-1.03 0-1.42zm-4.68 1.69c-.34 2.12-1.85 3.94-3.88 4.66-1.21.43-2.41.45-3.5.18-.41-.1-.48-.65-.13-.9C11.98 15.84 13 14.04 13 12s-1.02-3.84-2.58-4.92c-.35-.24-.29-.79.13-.9 1.09-.27 2.29-.25 3.5.18 2.02.72 3.54 2.54 3.88 4.66.05.33.07.66.07.98-.01.32-.03.65-.08.98z"></path>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </div></body></html>
```

what's wrong with the code? or what should I do so that it can runs in firefox like in chrome.

```html
when mouse hover, it should be.(X is svg picture, ccc is text)
                         +---+ |
                         | X | |
                         +---+ |
                    +--------+ |
                    | X cccc | | 
                    +--------+ |
                         +---+ |
                         | X | |
                         +---+ |
now in firefox, it become(text did not display, and others display position error)
                   +---+       |
                   | X |       |
                   +---+       |
                   +---+       |
                   | X |       |
                   +---+       |
                   +---+       |
                   | X |       |
                   +---+       |
```

but when I drag the button, it display correctly.

when I set element state hover in developer tool rather than use mouse, it work.

I can use max-width: calc(48px + 2.5vmin + 8em) , it work.

but I try calc(100% + 100vw) is same bad, it needs not just a big enough value.

only I set 100%(max-width) and use mouse at the same time will make a bad effect.
 why? it is strange.

Comment: Please explain **in words** what wrong means.

Comment: I put code into code snippet, and I draw a text picture now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the use of `min-width:100%` on hover creating this bad effect. You can use a fixed width instead that is big enough to fit all your texts:

```css
:root {
  --background: 255, 255, 255;
  --surface: 255, 255, 255;
  --color: 0, 0, 0;
  --shadow: 0, 0, 0, .25;
  --error-background: 211, 47, 47;
  --error-color: 0, 0, 0;
  --onBackground: 18, 18, 18;
  --onSuface: 18, 18, 18;
  --onError-background: 0, 0, 0;
  --onError-color: 255, 255, 255;
}

* {
  min-height: 32px;
  min-width: 32px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(var(--background));
  font-size: calc(12px + .625vmin);
  color: rgb(var(--color));
}

div {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.fabs {
  z-index: 6;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-content: baseline;
  will-change: clip-path, opacity;
  transition: clip-path .3s ease-out, opacity .3s ease;
  clip-path: inset(calc(100% - 64px - 5vmin) 0 0 calc(100% - 80px - 7.5vmin));
  overflow: hidden;
  contain: layout style;
}

.fabs>a {
  max-width: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
  max-height: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
  min-height: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
  border-radius: calc(24px + 1.25vmin);
  background-color: rgb(var(--surface));
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: .5px solid rgb(var(--color), .2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(var(--shadow));
  margin: calc(8px + 1.25vmin) calc(16px + 2.5vmin);
  transition: max-width .5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
}

.fabs:hover {
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

.fabs>a~a:hover {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.fabs svg {
  width: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
  stroke: rgba(var(--color), .7);
}

.fabs>a~a::after {
  content: attr(title);
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: calc(48px + 2.5vmin);
  margin-right: calc(24px + 1.25vmin);
  color: rgb(var(--color));
}
```

```html
<div class="fabs" id="fabs">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-4 -4 32 32">
            <line x1="6" y1="12" x2="18" y2="12"></line>
            <line x1="12" y1="6" x2="12" y2="18"></line>
          </svg>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:home()" title="Home">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-4 -4 32 32">
            <polyline points="7 10.2,7 17,10.5 17,10.5 12,13.5 12,13.5 17,17 17,17 10.2" fill="#fff0"></polyline>
            <polyline points="5 11,12 5,19 11" fill="#fff0"></polyline>
          </svg>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'})" title="Top">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-4 -4 32 32">
            <line x1="8" y1="7" x2="16" y2="7"></line>
            <polyline points="8 13,12 9,16 13" fill="#fff0"></polyline>
            <line x1="12" y1="10" x2="12" y2="18"></line>
          </svg>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:theme(+1)" title="Turn Theme">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-8 -8 40 40">
            <path fill="#fff0" d="M22.6 11.29L20 8.69V5c0-.55-.45-1-1-1h-3.69l-2.6-2.6c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0L8.69 4H5c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v3.69l-2.6 2.6c-.39.39-.39 1.02 0 1.41L4 15.3V19c0 .55.45 1 1 1h3.69l2.6 2.6c.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0l2.6-2.6H19c.55 0 1-.45 1-1v-3.69l2.6-2.6c.39-.39.39-1.03 0-1.42zm-4.68 1.69c-.34 2.12-1.85 3.94-3.88 4.66-1.21.43-2.41.45-3.5.18-.41-.1-.48-.65-.13-.9C11.98 15.84 13 14.04 13 12s-1.02-3.84-2.58-4.92c-.35-.24-.29-.79.13-.9 1.09-.27 2.29-.25 3.5.18 2.02.72 3.54 2.54 3.88 4.66.05.33.07.66.07.98-.01.32-.03.65-.08.98z"></path>
          </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I added some questions at the end of my issue.

Comment: @JinShengChen the issue is the use of percentage which is relative to parent width and the parent is set to position fixed so its width fit the width of its content and expressing the width of the content using percentage will create a kind of cycle which is the culprit of your bad effect. I don't know exactly why but I am sure it's related to the percentage value inside max-width